# How to restrict field level access in record types using page layouts

Tags: page-layout, record-type

I am working with record types and page layouts. 
How can we give the read-only permission to any specific field which under record types.
I am working with one object, which has two page layouts. I want one field of page layout should be read-only and it should be edit for other page layout.

Can any one help out this.

Answer (score 3):

In a page layout on the field properties you can set the permission to read only.

[image]

However there may be fields that you cannot do this with, e.g Account name on the Account object and for those you would need to set the permissions using Field Level Security on the Profile.

Then using Record Type assignment of page layouts you can make the fields editable on one record type only.

[image]